# Share a file between two node.js instances

Tags: node.js

I have this requirement.

In one application, A user creates his design and saves it. In another url, the user will have his application running i.e

```
http://localhost:3000/design   
http://localhost:3002/application
```

A user  publish his design changes and the application will have the new changes.

To meet this requirement, I can pass html and write the changes using fs each time. However, I want to know whether it is possible to use a single file between two instances and implement observer pattern i.e whenever some changes are done in designer file and saved, the same should be reflected in application without passing data each time.

Comment: use any of the `file watcher` modules available in Node.

Comment: File watcher modules are for application running on same instance..not for different instances I think

Comment: it's global, you have to install it in the applications where you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [fs.watchFile](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) or [fs.watch](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener)?

```
fs.watchFile('message.text', function (curr, prev) {
  console.log('the current mtime is: ' + curr.mtime);
  console.log('the previous mtime was: ' + prev.mtime);
});
```